# Spring JMS - IBM MQ has open input count issue

Tags: spring, jms, ibm-mq

We are using Spring JMS to connect IBM MQ in that  the MQ open input count keep on increase.is there any solution can we reduce the open input count. we are using  concurrent connection as 1 only.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow... Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Then add the missing information.

Answer (score 1):

The IBM MQ connection handle behaves differently with Spring configuration. If you are using the CachingConnectionFactory that spring provides, please read my answer in the below thread.

[JMS connections exhausted using WebSphere MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786449/jms-connections-exhausted-using-websphere-mq/43617832#43617832)

Please add more details to better understand the issue. The Apache camel will dynamically scale up and down the open input counts based on the load. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

That is a clear indication of your code not closing the queue you have opened. Close the consumer(s) you have created.

Comment: Shashi thanks for your answer. am not opening any connection (explicitly) and using onmessage method to read(consume) message from IBM MQ.is it possible to close consumers explicitly in spring JMS.If so provide me the code snippet that will helps a lot.

Comment: facing same issue, in fact in my case current queue depth also increases but I managed using thread pool but open input count is still problem for me.  Did you got any solution.  I am using Spring jmsTemplate with MQ 7.5