# IBM MQ Open input count shows 2 for websphere MDB with max sessions 1 (Causing reordering of messages)

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-mq, message-driven-bean

My issue is similar to : [Spring JMS - IBM MQ has open input count issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38720153/spring-jms-ibm-mq-has-open-input-count-issue)

I have set up my Message Driven Bean to have max-sessions 1 for sequential message delivery in Websphere. So i assume only one connection should be open to that queue. I do see that open input count is 2 some times. Some times its two different process as in the picture, sometimes its the same. Is it normal behavior of websphere? Please do advise. I am investigating a messsage re-ordering issue, this will be of great help.
[image: Queue connection shows 2 process]

Websphere Version 8.5.1 and IBM MQ Version is 7.0
MDB is configured via Activation Spec

Answer (score 1):

The 2 instances your queue is opened are different as one has the queue opened for browsing and the other has it open for destructive gets. So I don't really see how having it opened twice like these would affect the ordering of the messages.

MQ doesn't guarantee the ordering of messages by default. If message ordering is really important you should use message groups, which explicitly define the ordering of messages in the MQMD of each message.

Without message groups you need to meet a number of requirements to assume message ordering is kept by MQ.

Comment: Thanks much. As of now all messages has the same priority , a single sender and a single receiver (MDB max session 1) so it should have been delivered in order. I will check the message group implementation.